# How to change $index for two ngRepeats with same input but different filters?

Tags: angularjs

I've simulated my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/29mh8bfe/5/).

Looking into this html, you can see that I am doing two `ng-repeat`s with the same array as input, but different filters to each one:

```
<div ng-app='Lists'>
    <div ng-controller='listsController'>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat='item in listValues | filter : xxx track by $index' ng-click="update($index)">
                    <td>{{item.ref}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.others}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><hr/>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat='item in listValues | filter : yyy track by $index' ng-click="update($index)">
                    <td>{{item.ref}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.others}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><hr/>
        <div>{{updateIndex}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my js code:

```
var appModule = angular.module('Lists', []);

appModule.controller('listsController', function($scope) {
    $scope.listValues = [
        {'ref' : '1', 'others' : 'abc..'},
        {'ref' : '2', 'others' : 'def..'},
        {'ref' : '1', 'others' : 'ghi..'},
        {'ref' : '2', 'others' : 'jkl..'}
    ];
    $scope.xxx = function(a){
        return a.ref == 1;  
    };
    $scope.yyy = function(a){
        return a.ref == 2;  
    };
    $scope.update = function(i) {
        $scope.updateIndex = i;
    };
    $scope.updateIndex = "none";
});
```

The problem I'm stuck is that the `update(index)` function needs to change the object in the correct index of the `listValues` array. But as you can see clicking in the object of the second table gives me the `$index` of the first table.

How to work around this situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `$index` is doomed to fail, even if you iterate once. $index is the index of the current item in the *filtered* array. And that index is different from the index of the same element in the original, non-filtered array.

If you want to modify an item on click, don't pass its index as argument. Pass the item itself:

```
ng-click="update(item)"
```

Comment: I tried it now, but didn't work because the `update` function opens a modal, so the user can edit the values and the values can _only_ be saved when the user press confirm button. So I am copying the _item_ to another object inside the modal, and I need to know when the user clicks in the button the exact `index` to update in the array. Am I forgetting something obvious?

Comment: No, you don't need to know the index of the item to update. You just need to know the item to update. If you want to replace the old item by the new one, then find the index of the old item, using indexOf(), in the array, and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filters **use ng-if** which allows you to track items by index.Index will give exact click even list has duplicate items

```
<body>
    <div ng-app='Lists'>
        <div ng-controller='listsController'>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in listValues  track by $index" ng-click="update($index)" ng-if="xxx(item)=='1'">

                        <td>{{item.ref}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.others}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><hr/>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat='item in listValues track by $index' ng-click="update($index)" ng-if="item.ref=='2'">
                        <td>{{item.ref}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.others}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><hr/>
            <div>{{updateIndex}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```